# In which layer entities class must be defined?

Tags: c#, java, entity-framework

When creating a Business Model in which layer (GUI, BLL, DAL) entities class must be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entities are a part of your Business Logic. In your entities you define your business rules.

They should be ignorant of the type of Data Access you use. This can be done by using the  Repository pattern. In your BLL you define your Repository interfaces which act on your entities. In a separate infrastructure project, you will define an implementation for the Repositories.

If you pass your entities to your GUI is a matter of choice. Sometimes it can be beneficial to use special crafted classes for passing data to your view but in a small project you could opt for passing your entities directly to your GUI.

Comment: I agree with you. I see you use Microsoft Entity Framework. (Am I wrong but) it seems that Entity Framework should be efined in the DAL and/or is not ignorant of the type of Data Access you use.

Comment: Yep, I'm  a C#/Entity Framework developer :) Entity Framework supports different coding styles. You can use Database First, Model First or Code First. Code First has the nicest solution to begin completely database ignorant. Database and Model first can be configured to output POCO objects which are also database ignorant. In the end, you end up with a single project containing your entities and another project with your database infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the way you want to use your entity. If it's simple POCO object, that used as DTO from db to you application, so i think that best place will be DAL. If you want to use your entity like part of business logic and it has some functional - so BLL will be the best place. But I don't think that there are some cases when it should be used and defined in GUI

I think that it's a good practice to have an ViewModel for any GUI purposes. Because when you use EF than it means that you interact with SQL somehow (in most cases). So you data is normalized. For there other hand many times you need denormalized data for GUI. That why i prefer to use ViewModel for GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it in two places

Either create a new Layer Model/Entities (preferred)

or

Define them in Data Access Layer

Answer (score 1):

I would say: in their own layer. The GUI, the business layer and the data access layer all use the entities. But the GUI doesn't depend on the data access layer, and the data access layer doesn't depend on the service layer. So entities must be in their own domain layer.